# why jquery Ui date picker not showing in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to show jquery ui date picker in angular using this link
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
I do like that

```
function datePickerDirective() {

  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      date: '=',
      placeHolder: '@',
      isRequired: '=',
      name: '@'
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="date" placeholder="{{placeHolder}}" type="text" />',
    link: function($scope, iElem, iAttr) {

      $(iElem).datepicker({
        maxDate: "+3m +2w",
        minDate: new Date(),
        onSelect: function(date) {
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.date = date;
          });
        }
      });
    }
  };

  return directive;
}
```

But it is not showing datepicker

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/kW6eGmuPFxFvzZfKGZXv?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(iElem)` will refer to `<date-picker>` html element, not your actual `input` element in the template. So either, select the input inside that `<date-picker>` element, or use `replace:true` in your directive definition

`$('input',$(iElem)).datepicker(..)`

OR

```
scope: {
                date: '=',
                placeHolder: '@',
                isRequired: '=',
                replace:true,
                name: '@'
            },
```

Heres a working [fork](https://plnkr.co/edit/0HlGScG51Qk3WPD9c262?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Mixing jQuery and Angular is a bad idea. Use the AngularUI datepicker instead: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date.

Comment: yup but Currently I am using jquery UI only.please remove this answer

Comment: This should be a comment. And I agree, mixing is asking for issues